# Cannot find documentary for many things in tf.nn.seq2seq class in the tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

**tf.nn.seq2seq.embedding_attention_seq2seq**

I was searching  the above function in tensorflow api. But I counln't find that by the exact name. But similar function was there in the class **tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.embedding_attention_seq2seq**  .
Why they moved few from nn class to contrib class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google [just released TensorFlow 1.0 last week](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/migration), where the API has been updated, so things have been moved around. Because of the various contributions from the TF community, the contrib directory is reserved for this code, which has not yet been finalized for acceptance into core TF.

Check out the [README](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/README.md) on contrib:

> The contrib directory contains project directories, each of which has
>   designated owners. It is meant to contain features and contributions
>   that eventually should get merged into core TensorFlow, but whose
>   interfaces may still change, or which require some testing to see
>   whether they can find broader acceptance. We are trying to keep
>   duplication within contrib to a minimum, so you may be asked to
>   refactor code in contrib to use some feature inside core or in another
>   project in contrib rather than reimplementing the feature.

Comment: But I cannot find the documentation in the core tensorflow why is that ?

Comment: try this: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/  (use left side bar to disclose each section (tf, tf.layers, tf.contrib, tf.train, etc)

Comment: Well I went through it. but documentation for tf.nn.seq2seq has removed from it. I think as you mentioned it's only the documentation.